# Functionalities on Android and Google Play compatibility

Tags: android, autofocus

I had an application that require autofocus to work so its in the manifest file.

When I put my application on the Play Store some phones ar not in the compatibility list like :

- Xperia Tipo (ST21i)
- LG Optimus L3 (E430)

But according to the constructor specifications this phones have autofocus. I wonder if this is an issue on the play store (and if it the case where I can contact the developpers ?) or if this is an issue on the device is there is a way to allow it manually ?

Thanks in advance.

Erufu

Answer (score 1):

You can use this permission insted of autofocus in your menifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Yeah but in that case I will allow the phone without autofocus and as the app is used for scan QR Code it's not possible to allow a phone without autofocus ... (Client specications and worries ...)

Answer (score 0):

The two phones doesn't have autofocus ... that's it ...

Answer (score 0):

These models have no auto autofocus at all, just check de oficial technical sheet, there's no track of it.
XPERIA Tipo technical specification:

www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/st21/whitepaper_EN_st21_xperia_tipo.pdf

LG LG E430:

www.lg.com/uk/mobile-phones/lg-E430